# Distance of a point to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be the plane $x+2y+3z=11$. Find the shortest distance $d$ from the point $P=(2, 4, 5)$ to $T$, and the point $Q$ in $T$ that is closest to $P$.

This is just one of the questions on my assignment.
I'm not too sure where to begin.

Comment: You can easily look this up, this question has been asked several times, here on stackexchange and other websites. It takes just seconds....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal vector to the plane is $(1,2,3)$. A point in the plane is $(11,0,0)$. We can take the difference between $P$ and the point in the plane, and then project this onto the normal vector: $$\text{proj}_n{(11,0,0)-(2,4,5)}=\frac{(9,-4,-5)\cdot(1,2,3)}{14}(1,2,3)={-(1,2,3)}$$ So the distance is $$||-(1,2,3)||=\sqrt{14}$$ and the closest point is $$(2,4,5)-(1,2,3)=(1,2,2)$$ Note that $$x+2y+3z=1+4+6=11$$ as required.